# Socialauth-android get oAuth-token and use account information on device

Tags: android, oauth, socialauth

I am using the socialauth-android library to log users in with Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

So far I couldn't find a way to get the oAuth-token back. Is there a way to access it without reimplementing parts of the library?

Also, when I want to sign in using socialauth (see code below) I have to type in the username and the password manually although I have all accounts already set up with the device. Can you tell socialauth to use this accounts?

```
buttonFacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSocialAdapter.authorize(ActivityLogin.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
        }
    });
```

Comment: okay I found a way to get the token: `String token = mSocialAdapter.getCurrentProvider().getAccessGrant().getKey()`;

Comment: Could you answer your own question? It is not obvious that the answer is hidden inside this comment. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out the way to get the token is

```
String token = mSocialAdapter.getCurrentProvider().getAccessGrant().getKey();
```